# d3js diagonal in tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a Tree graph using d3.js with the Tree layout connected by lines using the Diagonal path generator.

My problem is that I want to render the nodes as rectangles and have the graph edges start at the right hand side of the node rectangle but finish on the left hand side of the child node rectangle. Right now they are co-incident which makes it look a bit messy.

I've tried using a projection on the diagonal but that modifies both the start and end points in the same way (say shifting them right by X pixels) rather than doing the opposite to each (for the start point, shift right X pixels but for the end point, shift left X pixels).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

As requested - here is the JS code I'm using to render my tree....

```
function renderTree (root) {    

var rect_width = 150;
var rect_height = 25;
var rect_corner_radius = 4;
var transition_duration = 200;

var tree = d3.layout.tree();

tree.size([900,700]);

var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
var links = tree.links(nodes);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection( function (d) {return [d.y, d.x];});

var canvas = d3.select(".treeCanvas");


var tree_link = canvas.selectAll(".treeLink")
                .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.oid;});

var tree_node = canvas.selectAll(".treeNode").data(nodes, function (d) { return d.oid;});

//transition existing nodes and links
tree_link.exit().transition().duration(transition_duration).remove();

tree_link.transition().duration(transition_duration).attr("d", diagonal);

tree_node.exit().transition().duration(transition_duration).remove();


tree_node.selectAll("rect").transition().duration(transition_duration)
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.x - rect_height/2; });

tree_node.selectAll("text").transition().duration(transition_duration)
                    .attr("dy", function (d) {return d.x +3;})
                    .attr("dx", function (d) {return d.y +3;});


//add new nodes & links

tree_link.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "treeLink")
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("fill", "none");

var tree_node_enter = tree_node.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("id", function(d) { return "node" + d.oid; })
.attr("class", "treeNode");

tree_node_enter.append("rect")
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("stroke", "steelblue")
.attr("stroke-width", "2")
.attr("x", function (d) { return d.y; })
.attr("y", function (d) { return d.x - rect_height/2; })
.attr("width", rect_width)
.attr("height", rect_height)
.attr("rx", rect_corner_radius)
.attr("ry", rect_corner_radius)
.on("click", function (d) { updateTree(d);});

tree_node_enter.append("text")
.attr("dy", function (d) {return d.x +3;})
.attr("dx", function (d) {return d.y +3;})
.attr("textLength", rect_width -6)
.text(function (d) { return d.className + "=" + d.id; });


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: Code added as requested. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting things like `dx` and `dy` manually for each link to get the spacing you want?

Comment: Hi Lars - how would I do that? On my tree_link.enter when I specify "d" attribute and feed the path generator? How do I address the start coordinates versus the end coordinates of "d" ?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, this was a comment for a different question. You should have a look at [`diagonal.target`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-diagonal_target), which will allow you to specify the end coordinates. In particular, you can shift those coordinates to the left hand side of the node.

Comment: Thanks Lars - I tried that and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Great. I'll add that as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The [`diagonal.target` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-diagonal_target) allows you to specify the coordinates of the end point of the diagonal. You can use it to shift the point to the left hand side of the node.